# How to get two equal columns, one column containing 3 equal height div "rows"?

Tags: css

I have two div columns, the right column contains dynamic list content, the left contains 3 divs which act like rows):

[image]

I've found many methods for getting equal height for the two main columns, but is there a way of getting the three div "rows" to be 33.33% height each as well?

Comment: What code do you currently have?

Answer (score 1):

The HTML code:

```
header
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="left_container">
        <div class="content">
            #1 left asd
        </div>
        <div class="content">
            #2 left asd
        </div>
        <div class="content">
            #3 left asd
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="right_container">
        <div class="content">
            right asd
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
footer
```

The CSS for this

```
div {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: block;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    height: 10em; /* should be px or em */
    margin: -1px; /* size of border */
    font-size: 20px; /* modulate the height of div like: 20x10=200px */
}
#wrapper {
    width: 100%;
}
#wrapper:after {
    clear: both;
    display: block;
    content: ' ';
}
#left_container,
#right_container {
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
}
#left_container .content {
    height: 33.33%;
}
#right_container .content {

}
```

Live example:
http://jsfiddle.net/Z2hpu/2/

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but this doesn't seem to work if the right column extends below the left: http://jsfiddle.net/Z2hpu/1/

Comment: just i don't check every details of your question. it's doing well now ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Give classes to your divs like "column" to the vertical divs and "row" to the inner horizontal ones for example. Then apply this css:

```
.column { height:600px; width:50%; }
.column > .row { height:33%; width:98%; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Flexbox can do this with the number of elements you've specified without fixed heights:

http://codepen.io/cimmanon/pen/Gmljd

```
.wrapper {
  display: -webkit-flexbox;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
}

.a, .b {
  display: -webkit-flexbox;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  -webkit-flex-flow: row wrap;
  -ms-flex-flow: row wrap;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  display: flex;
}

.a div, .b {
  border: 1px solid;
  -webkit-flex: 1 0 100%;
  -ms-flex: 1 0 100%;
  flex: 1 0 100%;
}

<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="a">
    <div>1</div>
    <div>2</div>
    <div>3</div>
  </div>

  <div class="b">
    b
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, this is interesting, I've not heard of flexbox before. But is it compatible with most browsers yet?

Comment: No.  This one requires Chrome, Opera, and IE10.  I bet if I tinkered with it a bit, I could get it working in Firefox and Safari as well.